# What are all those 'sd' devices in /proc/devices

Tags: linux, devices, proc

The `/proc/devices` file lists devices by major revision number and name. On my system it shows (partially):

```
Block devices:
259 blkext
  7 loop
  8 sd
  9 md
 11 sr
 65 sd
 66 sd
 67 sd
 68 sd
 69 sd
 70 sd
 71 sd
128 sd
129 sd
130 sd
131 sd
132 sd
133 sd
134 sd
135 sd
253 device-mapper
254 mdp
```

What are all those 'sd' devices? The first one (rev. no. 8) is probably `/dev/sda` but the rest of them don't show up in `/dev` - there are no devices with those major revision numbers.

I *do* see a list of devices:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7, 128 Jul 29 14:15 vcsa
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7, 129 Jul 29 14:15 vcsa1
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7, 130 Jul 29 14:15 vcsa2
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7, 131 Jul 29 14:15 vcsa3
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7, 132 Jul 29 14:15 vcsa4
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7, 133 Jul 29 14:15 vcsa5
crw-rw---- 1 root tty       7, 134 Jul 29 14:15 vcsa6
```

where the **minor** number might be a match - would /proc show **minor** revision numbers, and why are they called `sd`. Either way, I don't see any device with no. `135`.

Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first disk `/dev/sda` is `8:0` (major:minor), but the major number 8 contains the next 15 disks too ([`Documentation/devices.txt`](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.4/source/Documentation/devices.txt) in the kernel source):

```
  8 block       SCSI disk devices (0-15)
                  0 = /dev/sda          First SCSI disk whole disk
                 16 = /dev/sdb          Second SCSI disk whole disk
                 32 = /dev/sdc          Third SCSI disk whole disk
                    ...
                240 = /dev/sdp          Sixteenth SCSI disk whole disk

                Partitions are handled in the same way as for IDE
                disks (see major number 3) except that the limit on
                partitions is 15.
```

The rest are for the rest of your drives (major numbers 66-71 and 128-134 are similar, and the partitioning scheme is the same for all of them):

```
 65 block       SCSI disk devices (16-31)
                  0 = /dev/sdq          17th SCSI disk whole disk
                 16 = /dev/sdr          18th SCSI disk whole disk
                    ...


135 block       SCSI disk devices (240-255)
                  0 = /dev/sdig         241st SCSI disk whole disk
                    ...
                240 = /dev/sdiv         256th SCSI disk whole disk
```

Well, you probably don't have that many disks, and the system only generates the nodes that are required for the devices you actually have, so you don't see anything but `sda` and its partitions in `/dev`.

---

As for `vcsa` and friends, they're related to the virtual consoles:

```
  7 char        Virtual console capture devices
                  0 = /dev/vcs          Current vc text contents
                  1 = /dev/vcs1         tty1 text contents
                    ...
                128 = /dev/vcsa         Current vc text/attribute contents
                129 = /dev/vcsa1        tty1 text/attribute contents
                    ...
```

Also note that `/dev/vcs*` are character devices, not a block devices. The first letter in the `ls` output tells which one it is.

Answer (score 1):

It's just that there can be up to 16 * 1048576 `sd` block devices (which would have been ony 16 * 256 when dev_t was 16bits).

The code has:

```
    for (i = 0; i < SD_MAJORS; i++) {
            if (register_blkdev(sd_major(i), "sd") != 0)
                    continue;
            majors++;
            blk_register_region(sd_major(i), SD_MINORS, NULL,
                                sd_default_probe, NULL, NULL);
    }
```

To register those 16 major numbers.

And:

```
/*
 * More than enough for everybody ;)  The huge number of majors
 * is a leftover from 16bit dev_t days, we don't really need that
 * much numberspace.
 */
#define SD_MAJORS       16
```

Where:

```
/*
 * Device no to disk mapping:
 *
 *       major         disc2     disc  p1
 *   |............|.............|....|....| <- dev_t
 *    31        20 19          8 7  4 3  0
 *
 * Inside a major, we have 16k disks, however mapped non-
 * contiguously. The first 16 disks are for major0, the next
 * ones with major1, ... Disk 256 is for major0 again, disk 272
 * for major1, ...
 * As we stay compatible with our numbering scheme, we can reuse
 * the well-know SCSI majors 8, 65--71, 136--143.
 */
static int sd_major(int major_idx)
{
    switch (major_idx) {
    case 0:
        return SCSI_DISK0_MAJOR;
    case 1 ... 7:
        return SCSI_DISK1_MAJOR + major_idx - 1;
    case 8 ... 15:
        return SCSI_DISK8_MAJOR + major_idx - 8;
    default:
        BUG();
        return 0;       /* shut up gcc */
    }
}
```

Which shows how majors and minors are allocated.